# If $a,b,c>0, a+b+c=3$, minimize $\frac{2-a^3}{a}+\frac{2-b^3}{b}+\frac{3-c^3}{c}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=3$. 
Find the minimum value of the expression

$A= \frac{2-a^3}{a}+\frac{2-b^3}{b}+\frac{3-c^3}{c}$

I tried solving it, but I got nothing

Comment: Is the last term of the RHS correct? $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Is this JBMO 2015 #2? http://i.stack.imgur.com/20T4N.jpg

Comment: If the last term was $\tfrac{2-c^3}{c}$, then this problem would be a straightforward application of Jensen's Inequality.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 same here. Seems like most of the solutions to this used some form of factorization/obscure substitution I would never see :P. Note that the function isn't convex/concave in $[0,3]$ so we can't just do it in one step (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I computed the second derivative of $\tfrac{2-x}{x^3}$ instead of $\tfrac{2-x^3}{x}$. My mistake.

Comment: @NRSSA Do let us know if you intended the linked question or not.  Also indicate where you encountered this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%20%282%20-%20a%5E3%29%2Fa%20%2B%20%282%20-%20b%5E3%29%2Fb%20%2B%20%283%20-%20c%5E3%29%2Fc%20where%20a%2Bb%2Bc%3D3), this expression has a local minimum of approximately 3.87713 for a=0.865495, b=0.865495, c=1.26901. That checks out with a+b+c=3.

This should be the value of the answer, but I am not sure how to go about solving it without computational tools. This should be the minimum value however, as req'd in the question.

Comment: Usually mathematicians do not seek the answer, they usually seek understanding

Comment: Right, I completely agree with you; my answer does not contain any meaningful explanation, just a computation. I am eager to find out how to approach the optimization without such means.

Comment: Actually, $\sqrt[3]{2} \approx 1.25992$ is significantly different from $1.26901$.